# .htaccess to different subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver, apache2

I have following folder structure

```
root
  - production
    - tool
    - wordpress
    - subfolder
      - subfolder1
        - subfolder2
```

And a subdomain `sub.domain.com` where the root folder is `production`.

If I open the subdomain `sub.domain.com` I want that it redirects into the `wordpress` folder without changing the URL.

When opening `sub.domain.com/tool` it should redirect to `subfolder/subfolder1/subfolder2` without changing the URL.

Is this possible with only using `.htaccess` files?
Right now I have this in `production`:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wordpress/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.+) wordpress/$1 [L]
RewriteRule .* wordpress/ [L]
```

Which works, but changes the URL to `sub.domain.com/wordpress`.
And this in my `tool` folder, which doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/subfolder1/subfolder2/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.+) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/subfolder1/subfolder2/$1 [L]
RewriteRule .* %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/subfolder1/subfolder2/ [L]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure why this should cause a redirect, you are not setting the `R` flag. How is your "subdomain" implemented - a real vhost, or something "made to work" by additional rewriting somewhere?

Comment: So if you had any post in your WP with the slug `/foobar`, then I suppose you want `sub.domain.com/foobar` to show that WP post ...? I suppose at most that could work, if you did things the other way around - capture every request URL that starts with `tools/` (and probably with `subfolder/`) first, and only then let WP handle all the rest.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wordpress/$1 -f` would only be true for requests that match a physically existing file in the wordpress folder - but for a WP post that is reachable via `/foobar`, no such file exists to begin with.